# how to get all data in array for where clause in codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

this is my `vardump` which return array :

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [1]=>
  string(1) "5"
  [2]=>
  string(1) "9"
  [3]=>
  string(2) "13"
  [4]=>
  string(2) "17"
}
```

that array is `$cuisines_category`

i need to get that `1`,`5`,`...` for where clause, i have tried this to get all the value :

```
foreach($cuisines_category as $key => $value){
        $cuisines_category_all = $this->Control_panel_m->m_get_cuisines_name_by_id($value);
    }
```

but its only returing 1 value. I need to return all of them

guys can you help me how to get it?

thank you (:

p.s the long of array can be change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You overwrite the same variable `$cuisines_category_all` in each iteration of the loop so it will only contain the value from last iteration

Perhaps you want it to be an array in which case do

```
foreach($cuisines_category as $key => $value){          
      $cuisines_category_all[] = $this->Control_panel_m->m_get_cuisines_name_by_id($value);
}
```

Comment: thank you its works! (: now i get new problem, i try `var_dump` and i get all data in multidimensional array. do u know how to get all data in multidimensioanl array?

Comment: not clear what you are needing to do. No idea what your model method returns or what you want to do with results

Comment: after i var_dump `$cuisines_category_all` i got new multidimensional arrays with contain `cuisines_name_1` i want to get all of the `cuisines_name_1` without using offset, do u know how ?

Comment: get them into what?

Comment: get them for echo, which i will insert all them into my database

Comment: echo and database insert don't work together. Please start a new question that includes all relevant detils

Comment: i cant ask new question in 90min, no i mean its not echo. i need to get all the `cuisines_name_1` in multidimensional array and send it into database